# Calling a PHP Method from JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, function, web

I was under the impression that since JavaScript is client-side and PHP is server-side, that it is impossible to call PHP from JavaScript; however, this code snippet works:

```
<script>
  function otherCourse(){
    var course = prompt("prompt?");
    document.write("
      <?php
        $con->query("INSERT INTO `Courses` (`Name`) VALUES ('blah')");
      ?>
    ");
  }
</script>
```

Why does this work? The entry was inserted into the database

Comment: certainly you are wrong, that's not possible, re-check everything

Comment: I tested it again, and I have no idea how it is working, but the entry is getting in the database!

Comment: **http://php.net/language.basic-syntax.phpmode** - and please check the editing tools, you can quite easily paste code, try CTRL + K.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your PHP is being executed from the server side. Your PHP that you've embedded in the JavaScript never actually ends up rendering anything.

Test it by removing any calls to the `otherCourse` function, and you'll see that the query still runs.

Comment: It runs even when the function is not called. So its simply interpretting it as php code even though its inside a javascript function?

Comment: @Fractaly - Yes. Any code wrapped in PHP tags (`<?php /* code */ ?>`) within a PHP document will run as PHP, no matter where you put it.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP executes on the server before that JavaScript even reaches the client.

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment.